# Dependency Resolution Error while installing Zabbix 2.4 on Centos 7

Tags: installation, centos7, zabbix

I have installed rpm from this site [1- Zabbix 2.4 download page for centos7](http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/7/x86_64/)

And I have been following installation instructions on this site [2- Zabbix.org centos installation instructions](http://zabbix.org/wiki/InstallOnCentOS_RHEL)

first, I configure zabbix repository

```
rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el6.noarch.‌​rpm
```

But, then I realized this repository is for /rhel/6. Then I run the command below to change the zabbix repository which is for /rhel/7 , since I use centos 7.

```
rpm --import http://repo.zabbix.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX
rpm -Uv  http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Then, I try to install zabbix

```
yum install mysql-server zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql zabbix-agent zabbix-java-gateway
```

But I couldn't because of some dependency could not be installed.

```
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: libnetsnmp.so.20()(64bit)
Error: Package: iksemel-1.4-2.el6.x86_64 (zabbix-non-supported)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: iksemel-1.4-2.el6.x86_64 (zabbix-non-supported)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have searched a bit and I have came accross a lot of people has same problem and you can find some offered solutions to the problem. I have tried to implement the offered solutions but non of them solved the problem.

[3.1- Offered solution from centos.org/forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1637) : I could not understand this, I run the commands and result are shown below.

```
rpm -qR postfix
libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)

rpm -q mysql-libs
package mysql-libs is not installed
```

[3.2- Offered solution from centos.org/forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8870) This problem seems very similar but it does not helped either

[3.3- Offered solution from zabbix.com/forum](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-40830.html) This problem seems exactly same, and a solution is offered. But I could not understand it.

Also, I found that on Zabbix official documentation [4- Zabbix 2.4 manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages)

> Supported for versions: RHEL6, CentOS 6

centos 7 is not listed here, but it contradicts with Zabbix download page, since they provide a link for centos 7. you can check first link.

Please share if you have any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you are installing RHEL 7 version? 
I see "el6" - zabbix-server-mysql-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64 in your error output.

Comment: first I try to install this: `rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el6.noarch.rpm` After when I realise it should be centos 7, I run that command `rpm -Uv  http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm` . It seems yum still try to reach old repository.

Comment: @Jan Garaj, I have clean the yum caches and problem is resolved. Thank you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Jan Garaj pointed, the problem was yum try to install el6 packages, although I have changed the zabbix repository which is for rhel/7.

So, I have just cleaned the cache with the commands below and problem is resolved.

```
yum clean headers
yum clean packages
yum clean metadata
```

You can find more information about cleaning yum caches on this site: 
[Centos/clearing yum caches](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html)

You can find information about removing a yum repository on tihs site, Just cleaning cache solves this problem, so I did not try to remove yum repository. But, it can be useful if cleaning cache does not help. 
[serverFault/how to remove yum repo](https://serverfault.com/questions/509717/removing-yum-repository-in-centos)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while installing nginx. For me what helped was continuous release repository [CR](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/CR)

Usage:

```
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable cr
```